# What are the Automorphisms of the field over Q and generated by 5^(1/3)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I have tried to solve it.Is it correct to consider all the isomorphic fields containing different roots for the polynomial?

[image: Image for the solution]

Answer (score 1):

The only automorphism of $\newcommand{\Q}{\Bbb Q}\Q(5^{1/3})$
over $\Q$ is the trivial automorphisms. This is because the
only root of $X^3-5=0$ in $\Bbb R$ is $5^{1/3}$ and so that is also
the only root in $\Q(5^{1/3})$.

Comment: Why we have to consider only R? In my solution we can see that there are extension fields having elements of C too.

Comment: As $\Q(5^{1/3})\subset\Bbb R$ any automorphism of $\Q(5^{1/3})$ maps $5^{1/3}$ to a real number.

Comment: Now I got it. Thanks a lot. :-D